# What does this array function do? - C programming

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, while-loop

I was given this function and I need to explain what it does without other context.
What my interpretation is: The address of the first element of an array is inputted into `arrFunc` with some length `L1`, and an integer pointer `p` is declared and initialized to point to the first element of `arr1`.
The while loop is what confuses me. My interpretation is (and I'm a beginner when it comes to programming) is that if the contents of `p` (which I believe contains the address of the first element of `arr1`) is less than the address of the last element of `arr1`, then increment the value inside the first element by 5, then increment `p` to go on to the next element of the array. The biggest thing that confuses me about the while loop is the comparison of two addresses `(p<arr1+L1)`.

I guess my other question is, is the condition in the while loop comparing the two addresses, or is it comparing the values stored in those addresses?

```
void arrFunc(int *arr1, int L1)
{
    int *p = arr1;
    while(p< arr1 + L1)
    {
        *p+=5;
        p++;
    }
}
```

Comment: What does add 5 to each element mean?

Comment: by add 5 to each element, i guess i mean adding 5 to whatever value is stored in each element

Comment: Yes on the addition. Also `p` is originally set to the address of `arr1`. In the loop, `p` is incremented each iteration `p++;`. So the comparison just checks the address of `p` making sure it is less than `arr1 + l1` (one past the end of the array)

Comment: `*p+=5` simply says "derefernce `p` to reference the value stored at the address held as the value of `p`".  `+=5` is the same as `x = x + 5`. So using the pointer it is the same as `*p = *p + 5`

Comment: Ahh, so this function adds 5 to each element in the array??

Comment: Yes, yes, yes... Remember, a pointer is nothing but a variable that holds the address to something else as its value. To get the value of what is at that address, you dereference the pointer. Big picture here. `int *p = arr1;` sets the address held by `p` to the address of the first element in `arr`. `*p+=5` adds `5` to the value at the address held by `p`, `p++;` advances to the next element (the next integer).

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense now! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Good. That's pretty much all there is to pointers. Once you make friends with the fact it is just a normal variable that stores an address to something else instead of a value, and to get the value of the something else at that address,  you dereference -- you pretty much got it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function adds 5 to the elements of the provided array, but *only* to the first `L1` elements (might not be the whole array).

To answer the second question, about adding an `int` to a pointer, in terms of memory C will manage to add the right amount based on an element size ; meaning it doesn't simply add the `int` to the address, it adds

```
sizeof(*array) * intValue
```

It actually adds the size of an array element multiplied by that integer value. Here it adds `sizeof(int) * L1` to get

```
arr1 + L1
```

to be compared with `p`. (`p++`, similarly, is incremented, in terms of addresses, by `sizeof(int)`).

Answer (score 0):

This function takes an array of size L1 and add 5 to each of the element. So if an array of size 4 like following is inputted

```
10 20 30 40
```

After executing this function the output will be

```
15 25 35 45
```

Comment: Array of size L1